# How to tell if laptop was woken by rtc?

Tags: power-management, suspend, clock, wakeup

Say I set my laptop to wake every morning with rtcwake (e.g. `echo $(date +%s 'tomorrow 08:00') > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` in a cron job or in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99-set-alarm.sh`).

Now, I'd like to run a script from `/etc/pm/sleep.d/80-on-rtc-wake.sh` *only* if the laptop was woken by the RTC alarm. Is it possible to check that the laptop was in fact woken by the RTC alarm?

I know I can read `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` and it will be empty if the alarm is unset or alarm time has passed, but that leads to a race condition since I want to set the alarm for *next* morning.

Is there log or something that tells explicitly if the wake was caused by an rtc alarm?

Comment: "but that leads to a race condition since I want to set the alarm for next morning" -- so why not do the check right before adding the next alarm, or a placeholder to make the file non-empty to show that your script was there? Just a thought, I'm not entirely sure my answer makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I can (and probably will) do the set-alarm part in 80-on-rtc-wake.sh after reading that /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm was empty. But it still doesn't give me assurance that the emptiness is due to an rtc wake (e.g. the computer could have crashed at some point; it's a strong assumption). I can also add a check that time is between 8 and 9 am, but that's even more hacky …